# Expand and collapse rows in a grid

Tags: grid-layouts

Would someone have an idea on how to implement a table with rows that you can expand or collapse in a grid. An example could be found in a pivottable in Excel, for example here http://www.contextures.com/excelpivottableexpandcollapse.html.

I would use it for example to display the total of groups of entities and be able to see the components of the sum.

Such hierarchical table could be useful in many situations.

The question is just on the display aspect, not about pivottable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
data = RandomInteger[10, {5, 10, 5}];
```

**OpenerView**

```
Column[Map[OpenerView[{Grid[{Total@#}, Dividers -> All, ItemSize -> 3, Background -> Pink],
      Grid[#, Dividers -> All, ItemSize -> 3, Background -> LightBlue]}] &, data]]
```

[image]

**FlipView**

```
Column[Map[FlipView[{Grid[{Total@#}, Dividers -> All, ItemSize -> 3, Background -> Pink],
     Grid[Prepend[#, Total@#], Dividers -> All, ItemSize -> 3, 
          Background -> {LightBlue, 1 -> Pink}]}, 1] &, data]]
```

[image]

**See also:**

[tutorial / Views >> OpenerView](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Views.html#483391171)

[tutorial / Views >> FlipView](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Views.html#751148190)

Comment: Very nice, thank you.

Comment: @faysou, my pleasure. Thank you for the accept.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a generalisation of kguler's answer for OpenerView. It allows to handle tree-like structures.

Using the functions defined in my answer to [Nested OpenerView controls not aligned](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/66688/66) you can emulate OpenerView controls that nest well (i.e are aligned, which is not possible using OpenerView because of the recursive way it's built, there's always an extra space in sub layers). You need to copy the code from the previous link before execting this code. This code deals more with the recursion on a tree rather than with the display which is now easily handled with openerView and OpenerTree.

```
ClearAll@grid;
grid[x_,color_:None]:=Grid[{x},Dividers->All,ItemSize->4,Background->color];

leafExpand[object_]:=
    Module[{info,color},
        info=getLeafInfo@object;
        color=getLeafColor@object;

        {
            info
            ,
            grid[info,color]
        }
    ];

recursiveExpand[object_]:=
    Module[{recursiveExpansion,results,displays,result,display,children,color},

        children=getChildren@object;
        recursiveExpansion=TreeExpand/@children;

        color=getGroupColor@object;

        results=recursiveExpansion[[All,1]];
        displays=recursiveExpansion[[All,2]];

        result=groupAggregationFunction@results;

        display=openerView[grid[result,color],displays];

        {result,display}
    ];

ExpandTree[x_,header_]:=Map[TreeExpand,x][[All,2]]//OpenerTree[#,header]&;

getChildren=#[[2]]&;
groupAggregationFunction=Total;
getGroupColor=First;
getLeafInfo={#[[2]],#[[2]]}&;
getLeafColor=First;

TreeExpand[o:oo[color_,info_]]^:=leafExpand[o]
TreeExpand[o:gg[color_,info_]]^:=recursiveExpand[o];

x={gg[Pink,{gg[Pink,{oo[LightBlue,1],oo[LightBlue,2],oo[LightBlue,3]}],oo[LightBlue,1],oo[LightBlue,2],oo[LightBlue,3],gg[Green,{oo[LightBlue,1],gg[Black,{oo[LightBlue,1],oo[LightBlue,2],oo[LightBlue,3]}],oo[LightBlue,2],oo[LightBlue,3]}]}]};

ExpandTree[x,grid@{"a","b"}]
```