# Nested OpenerView controls not aligned

Tags: grid-layouts

This question is related to a previous question of mine, [Expand and collapse rows in a grid](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/65231/66)

I'm trying to have nested OpenerViews similarly to the answer of kguler, but they are not aligned. The problem is compounded if I add more nesting. How can I have aligned rows across levels, as in the end I want to add the rows by group, and not have to zigzag when reading?

A basic example of my problem is :

```
OpenerView[
    {
        Grid[
            {{1}}
            ,
            Dividers->All,ItemSize->3
        ]
        ,
        Grid[
            {{
                OpenerView[
                    {
                        Grid[
                            {{2}}
                            ,
                            Dividers->All,ItemSize->3
                        ]
                        ,
                        Grid[
                            {{3}}
                            ,
                            Dividers->All,ItemSize->3
                        ]
                    }
                ]   
            }}
        ]
    }
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 2):

You can roll you own to get things as you prefer. Bare bones toy code:

```
opener[Dynamic[open_]] := 
 EventHandler[Dynamic[If[TrueQ[open], "[-]", "[+]"]], 
  "MouseClicked" :> (open = ! open)]

open = {False, False}

Dynamic[
 Grid@Join[{
    {opener[Dynamic[open[[1]]]], 1},
    If[TrueQ[open[[1]]], {opener[Dynamic[open[[2]]]], 2}, {}],
    If[TrueQ[open[[1]]] && TrueQ[open[[2]]], {"[  ]", 3}, {}]
    }],
 TrackedSymbols :> {open}]
```

[image]

This gives you more flexibility in the sort of things you can make. [For example](http://ibnhconsulting.blogspot.com.au/2014/10/a-dynamic-accounting-application.html).

Answer (score 1):

Using the interesting answer of Mike, I managed to do the following which is quite easy to use. I use the vanishing sequence ##&[] instead of {}.

I didn't think I would spend so much time on this display issue, but it was nonetheless quite interesting.

```
ReleaseAllHold[expr_,firstLevel_:0,lastLevel_:Infinity] := Replace[expr, (Hold|HoldForm|HoldPattern|HoldComplete)[e___] :> e, {firstLevel, lastLevel}, Heads -> True];

emptyElement="  ";
customOpener[Dynamic[open_]]:=EventHandler[Dynamic[If[TrueQ[open],Opener[True],Opener[False]]],"MouseClicked":>(open=!open)];

expandOpener[openList_,element_,{},newLevel_]:=Hold[{myOpener[dynamic[openList[[newLevel]]]],element}];
expandOpener[openList_,element_,levels_,newLevel_]:=Hold[If[TrueQ[And@@openList[[levels]]],{myOpener[dynamic[openList[[newLevel]]]],element},##&[]]];

expandLine[openList_,openerView[head_,rest_],levels_]:=
    Module[{newLevels=levels,newLevel},
        newLevel=++$nOpeners;
        AppendTo[newLevels,newLevel];

        Sequence@@{
            expandOpener[openList,head,levels,newLevel]
            ,
            Sequence@@(expandLine[openList,#,newLevels]&/@rest)
        }
    ];

expandLine[openList_,element_,{}]:=Hold[{emptyElement,element}];
expandLine[openList_,element_,levels_]:=Hold[If[TrueQ[And@@openList[[levels]]],{emptyElement,element},##&[]]];

OpenerTree[tree_,firstLine_,defaultTreeOpenValue:(True|False):False]:=
    Module[{linesHeld},
        $nOpeners=0;

        DynamicModule[{openList},
            linesHeld=expandLine[openList,#,{}]&/@Prepend[tree,firstLine]//Hold@dynamic@Grid@#&;
            openList=ConstantArray[defaultTreeOpenValue,{$nOpeners}];
            linesHeld/.{dynamic->Dynamic,myOpener->customOpener}//ReleaseAllHold
        ]
    ];

grid[x_]:=Grid[{{x}},Dividers->All,ItemSize->3];
l={grid[1],openerView[grid[2],{openerView[grid[3],{grid[4],grid[5]}],grid[6]}],grid[7],openerView[grid[8],{grid[9],grid[10],grid[11]}]};

OpenerTree[l,grid["head"],False]
```

Comment: related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/66772/66