# Collapse / expand a balance sheet using an OpenerView

Tags: grid-layouts

I am a relatively inexperienced *Mathematica* user, so I apologise if there is a simple answer to this question. I would like to create a balance sheet that can be collapsed/expanded as necessary.

I have been trying to modify the code that has been shared [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/65231/expand-and-collapse-rows-in-a-grid/66772#66772) by user faysou, but so far I've been unable to get the results I want.

Essentially I'd like to be able to replicate grouping as in Excel like this:

[image]

Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

#### Update

Here is a link to my [code](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/65231/expand-and-collapse-rows-in-a-grid/66772#66772)

I can't figure out how to modify `gg` and `oo` so that it will accept the format of `{"Cash at bank", 20, 30}`.

Comment: Did you try using the other answer to the linked question?

Comment: What could you achieve by modifying the linked code and what exactly couldn't you achieve.